# Log4j vulnerability with org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework

Tags: wso2, log4j2, wso2-identity-server

I am getting log4j-core -> 2.12.0 vulnerability with org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework

As per the github link - https://github.com/wso2/product-is/blob/v5.11.0/pom.xml
the compatible version for WSO2 IS v5.11 is 5.18.187

But as I checked over maven also, the specified version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wso2.carbon.identity.framework/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework/5.18.187
is log4j core vulnerabilities in compile dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wso2.carbon.identity.framework/org.wso2.carbon.identity.testutil/5.18.187

Could you please suggest, if I should go with upgrading the version of org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework or should just add direct dependency for log4j-core 2.17.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading `org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework` might lead in to breaking changes and updating `log4j-core dependency` will not resolve the issue since there can be other components whcih are also affected by this vulnerability.

WSO2 has already identified and fixed this. I would like to recommend you to download and use the latest Identity Server version (IS 6.0.0) from the official [WSO2 website](https://wso2.com/identity-server/) or from [git releases](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v6.0.0). The WSO2 team has paid special attention to fixing most of the 3rd party vulnerabilities in this release and there are so many [new features available](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/about-this-release/).

**Updated 1:**
You can follow the temporary solution specified in this [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=180948677) if you don't have a paid subscription or are unable to get the latest Identity Server product (NOTE that it is a temporary fix).

Comment: Do we have any update for v5.11 in git releases?

Comment: Also, could you highlight the difference between binaries from WSO2 website and git releases

Comment: There are no updates for v5.11 publicly. Only the paid customers are getting the latest fixes, improvements and security updates on top of v5.11.

Once a security issue is identified it is fixed in the public branch. Therefore the fixes are available for the public after the next release and that is v6.0.0.

Comment: It seems like the next release v5.12.0-beta3 is also available using the log4j v2.17.1. Can I try to use the same or are there any issues with that and I should try for 6.0.0? Also, it would be great if you could highlight the difference between binaries from WSO2 website and git releases

Comment: Get the IS 6.0.0[1] since it is the GA version. [1] - https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v6.0.0

Comment: Unlike the previous version WSO2 doesn't update the zip as the artifacts. In that case, you need to build from the scratch. Or you can download from the website.

Comment: When you are getting a IS from the pack keep the following in mind. The packs from the website will come under the EULA 3.2. If someone is downloading from the WSO2 website, ie the commercial version they can use it for evaluation purposes (non-commercial) but if they are using it for commercial purposes like development, testing and production they need to have a subscription.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Would  the mitigation script suggested in https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=180948677 serve the purpose of making the product non-vulnerbale to log4j attacks?

Comment: As per the doc, it should work. But please note that it is a temporary script.

Comment: Temporary in what sense? What if we integrate that in Dockerfile? The doc states for ubuntu. Do we have anything for Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading the org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework would not be compatible with the other modules in the distribution and I recommend not doing so since it could lead to some breaking changes in the product features.

And upgrading the log4j-core dependency in the org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework to the 2.17.2 version alone would not work since there are other artifacts that were affected by the log4j vulnerability.

Since this vulnerability was identified, WSO2 has released an updated version for the product-is which you can download from their website.
The **Version 5.11.0 - SERVICE PACK 01** which you can download from [here](https://wso2.com/identity-and-access-management/previous-releases/) would have the updated product-is v5.11.0 with the fixes for the log4j vulnerability. And it also includes bug fixes for the initial 5.11.0 release.

Hence, I recommend going with the already existing 5.11.0 - SERVICE PACK 01
instead of manually updating the affected artifacts.

Comment: I am trying to use the binary from https://github.com/wso2/product-is/blob/v5.11.0/pom.xml. Seems like this is the updated one. For now I am not sure if downloading and using Version 5.11.0 - SERVICE PACK 01 would be permissible.  But if you could highlight whether over github we have any updated versions, then that would be helpful. Also, we are trying to integrate some plugins and those plugins are using org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework libraries for extending wso2 authenticators, etc. So updating binary may or may not have an impact.

Comment: I checked and the binary seems to be using log4j version 2.17.0 but I am more concerned about the plugins and the libraries being used in the plugins

Comment: https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v6.0.0 has the log4j-core 2.17 version.